# Change a value of a key by Variable string in nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have an object of a state with some properties
for example

`function (location){ obj = { kids : { eyal : 21, noam :15 } pets : { dog : 5,  cat :2 } } }`

now I want to change eyal value

`location = "kids.eyal"`

if im doing

`setobj((prevobj) => { ...prevobj, [location] : 22 })`

it create new parameter in obj Kids.eyal = 22 instead of changing eyal in kids to 22
how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Logic.**

- Split the location on `.`
- Loop through the location array except for the last node.
- Replace the last node object which is the required target with the required value.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const obj = { kids : { eyal : 21, noam :15 }, pets : { dog : 5,  cat :2 } };
const targetLocation = "kids.eyal";
const pathArray = targetLocation.split('.');
const lastNode = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
let node = obj;
pathArray.forEach((path, index) => node = index === pathArray.length - 1 ? node : node [path]);
node[lastNode] = 22;
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```js
oldObj = { kids : { eyal : 21, noam :15 } }

function updateOneKidAge(obj,theKid) 
{
  const [kidName, newAge] = Object.entries(theKid)[0]
  return { kids : {...obj.kids, [kidName]: newAge}};
} 

console.log(updateOneKidAge(oldObj, {eyal: 22}))
```

Comment: It wont help because the object the need to be change is based on the parameter that the function get, and if there is two nested objects it wont work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can't use obj.property format inside [] brackets. You'll have to send the both properties separately. Something like

```
location = ["kids","eyal"]
```

and then use it there as:

```
setobj((prevobj) => { ...prevobj, [location[0]][location[1]] : 22 })
```

Hope it resolves the issue